# Bootstrap white bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am working on my personal website. Everything looks good on screen sizes that're above a size that I'm not sure about but it's around small screen sizes. When I hit that said small width I get this white bar on the right of my screen.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <title>Dylan Hobday | Web Developer</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Index.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default white" id="navbar" role="navigation">
         <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dylan Hobday</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active">
                     <a href="#"><b>About</b></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">Projects</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">Hire</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.container -->
      </nav>
      <div class="page-header">
         <h1><b>About</b></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="Wrapper" id="background">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                  <h1>Hello there, welcome to my site.</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1" id="row2">
                  <h2><b>Who Am I?</b></h2>
                  <p>I am an aspiring web developer working to become a professional. This website is going to serve as a home for all of my projects, ideas, and discussions to show to potential employers.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/js/Index.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/js/Bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
Width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.Wrapper{
Width: 100%;
height: 667px;
background-image: url('Background.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
.white{
background-color: white;
}
.navbar {
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 26;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
font-size: 17px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
.container{
Width: 100%;
Height: 100%;

}
.page-header {
Font-size: 30;
margin: 0px;
background-color: #1D262C;
color: white;
Height: 100px;
border: none;
}
h1 {
margin: 0px;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-top: 30px;
}
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 14;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.row {
color: #5E5E5E;
position: relative;
top: 30px;
}
.active {
color: black;
}
#head{
padding: 0px;
}
p {
font-size: 24px;
}
#row2{
float:left;
position: relative;
top: 30px;
color: #292929;
Width: 500px;
}
h2 {
color: black;
}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the width of #row2. Due to bootstrap being responsive, when the screen width is less than 500px bootstrap will adjust all of the elements to be the width of the screen but that element will still be 500px.

If you want that container to be 500px for a specific resolution I would recommend creating a @media query to support it or you could also set max-width: 500.

Comment: Also, please be sure to include jquery and bootstrap's javascript in that order in the head of your pages. Otherwise your nav menu will not toggle when on a mobile device/resolution. It looks good though! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and compliment. It works great now.